# An inequality on tubular neighborhood of curve $\Gamma$

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $D\subseteq \mathbb{C} $ be bounded and simply connected domain, $\Gamma = \partial D \in C^2 $, parallel strip $$D_h := \{ z = x + \eta h \nu(x) | x \in \Gamma, \eta \in [-1, 1]\},
$$
where $h>0$ is sufficiently small and the normal $\nu(x)$ is directed into the exterior of $D$. Set $z_1 = z_1(\eta) =w_1  + \eta h \nu(w_1)$ and $z_2 = z_2(\eta) = w_2  + \eta h \nu(w_2)$ with $w_1 \neq w_2 \in \Gamma$ and $\eta \in[-1,1]$, [Kress, Linear integral equations, p 111] tells that
$$
\min\{ \vert z_1(-1) - z_2(-1)\vert, \vert z_1(1) - z_2(1)\vert \} \leq \vert z_1(\eta_1) - z_2(\eta_2) \vert
$$
holds for arbitrary $\eta_1, \eta_2 \in [-1,1]$.

Here assume $ w_i = w(s_i) = (x(s_i), y(s_i))^T $, $\nu(w_i) = (\dot{y}(s_i), -\dot{x}(s_i))^T$ $i = 1,2$, where $ w = w(s) $ is the Arc length parameterization of $\Gamma$. Now
$$
\vert z_1(-1) - z_2(-1) \vert^2 =  (x(s_1) - x(s_2))^2 + h^2 (\dot{y}(s_1) - \dot{y}(s_2))^2 - 2h(x(s_1) - x(s_2))(\dot{y}(s_1) - \dot{y}(s_2)) +   \\
(y(s_1) - y(s_2))^2 + h^2 (\dot{x}(s_1) - \dot{x}(s_2))^2 + 2h(y(s_1) - y(s_2))(\dot{x}(s_1) - \dot{x}(s_2))  \\
\vert z_1(1) - z_2(1) \vert^2 =  (x(s_1) - x(s_2))^2 + h^2 (\dot{y}(s_1) - \dot{y}(s_2))^2 + 2h(x(s_1) - x(s_2))(\dot{y}(s_1) - \dot{y}(s_2)) +   \\
(y(s_1) - y(s_2))^2 + h^2 (\dot{x}(s_1) - \dot{x}(s_2))^2 - 2h(y(s_1) - y(s_2))(\dot{x}(s_1) - \dot{x}(s_2))  \\
$$
If $ \vert z_1(-1) - z_2(-1) \vert^2 = \vert z_1(1) - z_2(1) \vert^2$ take place, then
$$
(x(s_1) - x(s_2))(\dot{y}(s_1) - \dot{y}(s_2))- (y(s_1) - y(s_2))(\dot{x}(s_1) - \dot{x}(s_2)) = 0.
$$
With further assumption that $\dot{x}(s_1) - \dot{x}(s_2) \neq 0$, it gives that
$$
\frac{\dot{y}(s_1) - \dot{y}(s_2)}{y(s_1) - y(s_2)} = \frac{\dot{x}(s_1) - \dot{x}(s_2)}{x(s_1) - x(s_2)} = k \neq 0.
$$
Thus
$$
\vert z_1(-1) - z_2(-1) \vert^2 = \vert z_1(1) - z_2(1) \vert^2 =  (1+k^2 h^2)[(x(s_1) - x(s_2))^2 + (y(s_1) - y(s_2))^2]  \\
>\vert w_1 - w_2 \vert^2. \\
$$
This is a contradiction to the inequality mentioned above. How can we deny this case?

Edit: There seems to be something wrong in the inequality.